# Cannot get Custom Block to correct area on page?

Tags: blocks, custom, index

I am at a loss. I am trying to learn how to place this block on the index of my site but I cannot for the life of me get it to appear in the right area but I have been following guides to no avail.

I want my block to appear under the 'New Products' within the default sample data (After Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_New) but no luck. So far I am stuck at getting the block to appear so I can then do the rest. **Edit: Have it working by hardcoding but not Progmatically**

What I have so far is my module SiteTest and I am using the sample data with (rwd theme)
config.xml

```
        <?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Francis_SiteTest>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </Francis_SiteTest>
    </modules>

    <frontend>
      <layout>
        <updates>
            <Sitetest>
                 <file>Sitetest.xml</file>
             </Sitetest>
         </updates>
      </layout>
    </frontend>

    <global>
        <blocks>
            <Sitetest>
                <class>Francis_SiteTest_Block</class>
            </Sitetest>
        </blocks>
    </global>
</config>
```

My Block called block.php

```
<?php
class Francis_SiteTest_Block_block extends Mage_Core_Block_Template
{
    // my large working method in here
}
```

My controller in IndexController.php

```
<?php
    class Francis_SiteTest_IndexController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action{
    public function indexAction(){
          $this->loadLayout();
          $this->renderLayout();
    }

    public function viewAction(){
          $this->loadLayout();
          $this->renderLayout();
    }
}
```

Followed up with app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/Sitetest/block.phtml simply having my code I want executed

I expected this to render Under the New Products but I don't know where I have gone wrong. (or how badly for that matter).

Answer (score 1):

You need to tell magento to use your radiatortest.xml by adding below lines in your modules's config.xml after `</modules>` tag

```
<frontend>
    <layout>
       <updates>
            <radiatortest>
                 <file>radiatortest.xml</file>
             </radiatortest>
        </updates>
    </layout>
</frontend>
```

Try this..

Comment: And don't forget to clear caches.

Comment: Well that seems to be one issue fixed (I had that originally then got ride of it as it wasn't in other tuts.) Sadly still no Hello World though!

Comment: Can you see what error is coming in error.log or system.log file?

Comment: Placed the error in above text due to size.